# Android SDKManager STILL won't open

Tags: java, android

I downloaded and installed the latest Java JDK. Installed it to a space-less directory: "C:\ProgramData\Java\jdk-10.0.1".

I've got an environment variable:  JAVA_HOME which points to that directory.
Inside the PATH variable, I added %JAVA_HOME%\bin;

I downloaded the command-line tools, but when I double-click the SDKmanager.bat file in the bin folder, like everyone experiences, it flashes and vanishes.

I've tried the environmental variables fixes.
I've tried to replace data in the bat (there aren't even any references to java to fix).

I'm SoL and really need the help!

Thanks

-Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SDKManager only works with JDK 8. You'll want to install that instead of JDK 10.

Comment: Wow ok, I'll give that a test now, thank you!! If that works, I'll be happy but also supremely disappointed that something like this exists for developers to deal with, as if things are challenging enough.

Comment: Hmm well, all 3 .bat files still vanish instantly but if I run "sdkmanager -list" from terminal, I no longer get that weird error and instead I'm told:

Warning: File C:\Users\MyName\.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
Warning: Failed to find package -list

Comment: Try blowing away the .android folder.  Something may have gotten corrupted.

Comment: Thank you, that got things moving along...I've had to do so many changes, destroying that is a good idea. My biggest problem right now in Unity is that, whenever it tries to do something Android related (like fetch dependencies, etc) it comes back telling me it can't find the Android SDK manager tool. Of course, the paths set in Preferences -> External Tools are correct, so I don't know what's wrong! D:

Comment: Glad to hear. Please accept my answer if you feel it solved your original question.  The Unity problem will require another post to Stackoverflow or Unity Answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try launching .bat file from terminal (cmd). That should show you what the error is.

Comment: When I run the android.bat in the root folder, I'm told it's deprecated (it also flashes when I double click it, this is me navigating via terminal).